# DTO from json in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, dto

I have the following JSON structure that I getting from the server:

```
{
    "a": {
        "something": "something",
        "something2": {
            "test": "12345",
            "test2": "1234",
         },
        "something3": "something3"
    },
    "b": {
         "something": "something",
        "something2": {
            "test": "12365",
            "test2": "12",
         },
        "something3": "something3"
    }
 }
```

I can get more objects than "a" and "b".

I need to create DTO in Kotlin, I tried this DTO:

```
data class Root(
  val root: Map<String, Something>
)
data class Something(
  val something: String,
  val something3: String,
  val something2: Something2
)

data class Something2(
  val test: String,
  val test2: String
)
```

I use Retrofit library, it automatically parse JSON data to kotlin data class
I always get null from this DTO, how to write DTO for this JSON structure correctly?

Comment: What library do you use for JSON parsing? Share your kotlin code

Comment: I use GSON.  I've already shared kotlin data clasess

Comment: sorry, i did mean you should share the code that performs parsing. P.S. it looks like you are trying parse into `Root` class but since there is no `root` property in given json, so you should parse into `Map<String, Something>` directly

Comment: I got it. I use also retrofit it automatically parse into my data classes fields